# Merging pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I need help. I've to merge this DataFrames(examples) by adding new column and put percents there.
If 'level'<5000 it's NaN, if 5000<'level'<=7000 it's 5%, if 7000<'level'<=10000 it's 7% and etc..

```
import pandas as pd
levels = pd.DataFrame({'lev':[5000,7000,10000],'proc':['5%','7%','10%']})
data = pd.DataFrame({'name':['A','B','C','D','E','F','G'],'sum':[6500,3000,15000,1400,8600,5409,9999]})
```

[image: Image with result which I need Click]

My efforts do solve this... It doesn't work and I don't understand how to solve this.

```
temp = data[data['sum'] >= levels['lev'][2]]
temp['proc']=levels['proc'][2]
lev3 = temp
temp = data[levels['lev'][1]<=data['sum'] and data['sum']<=levels['lev'][2]]
temp['proc']=levels['proc'][1]
lev2 = temp
temp = data[levels['lev'][0]<=data['sum'] and data['sum']<=levels['lev'][1]]
temp['proc']=levels['proc'][0]
lev1 = temp
data = pd.concat([lev1,lev2,lev3,data])
```

Comment: you should show the steps that you've taken to try to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply a function to each row like this:

```
import pandas as pd

def levels(s):
    if 5000 < s <= 7000:
        return '5%'
    elif 7000 < s <= 10000:
        return '7%'
    elif s > 10000:
        return '10%'

df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['A','B','C','D','E','F','G'],'sum':[6500,3000,15000,1400,8600,5409,9999]})
df['Percent'] = df.apply(lambda x: levels(x['sum']), axis=1)

print(df)

  name    sum Percent
0    A   6500      5%
1    B   3000    None
2    C  15000     10%
3    D   1400    None
4    E   8600      7%
5    F   5409      5%
6    G   9999      7%
```